# 'x' must be numeric Traceback: for computing correlation for a matrix

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I want to compute the correlation between each column within a matrix.  But it throw an error: "Error in cor(sample, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"): 'x' must be numeric Traceback:

1. `cor(sample, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")`
2. `stop("'x' must be numeric")"`

This is what I did:

```
data = read.csv("mail.csv", header=F)

sample = data[-(1),-(1)]

cor(sample, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

My data set looks like this: I would appreciate if someone could tell me where I did wrong? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Hwj.png)

Comment: looking at str(data) could give you a clue.

Answer (score 5):

Run

str(data)
to look at your data types of your columns - example: numeric, factor, integer. 
See which column is not numeric which should be, and then ... I'm not very good about referring to columns in a matrix so put it into a **dataframe**. Rename your column, and take it back into a **matrix**.

```
data = as.data.frame(data)

data$column = as.numeric(data$column)
where "column" represents your issue column.  

data = as.matrix(data)
```

There now you can rerun your code.

Comment: in addition to what @Yaseem has said, correlation test requires numeric class so you can also use `library("dplyr")`
`select_if(sample, is.numeric)` to ensure you select numeric variables from your dataset